# Can I use "INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS" in MySQL triggers to avoid inserting duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, duplicates

Can I use "INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS" in MySQL triggers to avoid inserting duplicate records such as --

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'John') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` = 1);
```

When I use this sentence in a MySQL trigger, I got an error prompt and failed to create the trigger.

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` = 1) at line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IGNORE` :

```
INSERT IGNORE `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'John')
```

It will not insert nor throw the error if the row already exists.

You must to know that it is based on the key (of the table) to know if it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`` INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`)
    SELECT 1, 'John' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `user` WHERE `id` = 1) ``

Comment: Thank you very much! This is also a good way to solve my problem.